# Does Adobe Brackets' s Theseus debugger for Node.js have a breakpoint option as well?

Tags: node.js, debugging, adobe-brackets

I'm currently loving Theseus for dealing with the usual callback hell, but I still have some problems where I need to set a breakpoint and trace through.

I'm currently having to kill my app, start node with --debug, trace through, kill my app, start the app with node-theseus, rinse and repeat. I also find myself having to use a ton of un-necessary immediate functions just so that Theseus gives more information and that's a bad design.

Is it possible to use Theseus with breakpoints? I've tried searching around the GitHub page, StackOverflow and forums, but with no luck so far.

Am I missing something? Because Theseus with breakpoints would be the best debugging environment I've ever worked with.

Answer (score 1):

I just found some relevant info from the Theseus team:
https://github.com/adobe-research/node-theseus/issues/11

So no, it's not possible to use Theseus with breakpoints.

Basically(as far as I can tell) Theseus generates a lot of extra code and it's really difficult to make a source map for the original code. The Theseus team is working on it, but it doesn't look like that feature will be available soon.